# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField eliminated from POST when using jquery.post

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

I'm not sure what to do about this one.  I have a django form with two ModelMultipleChoiceField fields.  They show up properly in the web page, with the correct objects as options in the Select.  I use them to assign permissions to groups, like the django admin site does.  The problem is, when I intercept the submit with jquery, and call serializeArray() on the form, the two Select elements from the form are removed from the returned data because the val() of the element is null (jquery-1.9.1.js, line 7321).

The form:

```
class GroupUpdateForm(forms.Form):
    group_id = forms.IntegerField(label='', required=False)
    avail_perms = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Permission.objects.none(), \
                                            label='Available Permissions')
    assign_perms = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Permission.objects.none(), \
                                            label='Assigned Permissions')
    name = forms.CharField(label='Group Name', required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.group = kwargs.pop('group', None)
        super (GroupUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        has_perms = self.group.permissions.all()
        self.fields['assign_perms'].queryset = self.group.permissions.all()
        self.fields['avail_perms'].queryset = Permission.objects.all().exclude(id__in=has_perms)
```

My javascript currently is extremely basic, to track down the issue:

```
function saveGroupPermissions() {
    var dataArray = $('#groupEditForm').serializeArray();
    $.post('/sdc/admin/editGroup/' + parseInt($('#group_id').text()) + '/', dataArray, function(data){
        return true;
    });
}
```

What are my options, or how can I prevent my Selects from being removed so I can post them?

Edit:
Just tried it without jQuery, and the same thing is happening.  A regular submit removes the two ModelMultipleChoiceField selects from the POST and body.  Where am I going wrong?

Edit 2:
I tried forcing the dataArray to include the Select values like so (updated javascript file), but while the dataArray now includes an object for the added permissions

```
"["chargeback | category | Can add category"]"
```

when it gets to the view, the request.POST does not include that object.

```
function saveGroupPermissions() {
    var dataArray = $('#groupEditForm').serializeArray();

    //get all the added permissions and the removed permissions
    var added = $('.assignedPerm.added')
    var addedNames = new Array();
    if (added.length > 0) {
        for (var i=0; i < added.length; i++){
            addedNames.push(added[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
    var jAdded = JSON.stringify(addedNames);
    var addedData = {
        name:'addedData',
        value:jAdded
    }

    dataArray.push(addedData);

    $.post('/sdc/admin/editGroup/' + parseInt($('#group_id').text()) + '/', dataArray, function(data){
        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: does the `dataArray` have the values ? Also, in the view, how are you capturing the form details ?

Comment: @karthikr No, the dataArray, with jQuery, does not have any values for the two Selects.  Since the .val() of those elements is Null, jQuery removes them from the dataArray.  The form isn't an issue, as the request.POST and request.body do not have the selects included, so there's no data to capture.  The request doesn't include them whether or not I'm using jQuery, so no matter what, those two selects are not included in the POST.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that since the option elements were not selected, the select didn't give any value to the POST, whether jQuery or not.  I have to force, through jQuery, the added or removed option elements to be selected

```
$('.added').prop('selected', true);
$('.removed').prop('selected', true);
```

Once I do that, everything works fine.